# asp.net mvc 5 create new rows in detail table at same time as master table

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

So I am using asp.net mvc5 . I used database first approach to create simple web application. My question is how can I create child record when parent record is created. Let's say I have 3 tables that is (1)Students (2)Subject and (3)StudentSubject.

Sample data can be

```
students            Subjects           StudentSubject
--------------      ---------          ----------------
ID  Name           SID  SName           ID   SID
--------------      ---------          ----------------
1  St1             1  Sub1               1    1
2  St2             2  Sub2                
                   3  Sub3                
                   4  Sub4
```

So in above example student "St1" is enrolled in subjects "Sub1" .

I am able to create 3 views that can create new student, new subject and even new record in table StudentSubject.

But my question is how can I create records in table StudentSubject at the same time when I create record in table Student.

So my view can have fields like

ID, 
name, 
SubjectName

and if I enter

```
ID             3 
name           St3  
SubjectName    Sub2
```

and I click save, it should first create record in table Students and then in table StudentSubject based on subject selected.

So now the tables should look as below

```
students            Subjects           StudentSubject
--------------      ---------          ----------------
ID  Name           SID  SName           ID   SID
--------------      ---------          ----------------
1  St1             1  Sub1               1    1
2  St2             2  Sub2               3    2 
3  St3             3  Sub3                
                   4  Sub4
```

Thank You.

Comment: What have you tried? When you click save, do you have it creating the Student record at least?

Comment: Thanks for reply.Yes I am able to create Student and also StudentSubject  independently. Like I said problem is I want to create StudentSubject   record at the same time I create Student record.

Comment: Could you accept my answer please if it helped you?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without sharing any of your code it is hard to tell what your problem is. Here is my best guess at a solution without seeing any of your code:

```
using (var context = new MyContext())
{
  var myNewStudent = new Student()
  {
    //initialize your student
  };
  context.Students.Add(myNewStudent);
  context.SaveChanges();
  //get the identity column from the inserted student
  int id = myNewStudent.ID; 
  var myNewStudentSubject = new StudentSubject()
  {
    SID = id
  }
  context.StudentSubjects.Add(myNewStudentSubject);
  context.SaveChanges();
}
```

Perhaps you should explain what you mean by "at the same time" on these inserts, and why *you* think it is necessary.

Comment: Thanks Jack. By "At the same time", I mean I want to create StudentSubject  when student record is created. Of Course I have to select Subjects for the new student that is getting created. Right now I first create student. Then in diffrent page I select newly created student and I select subject from list of subjects and I save. I will try to put some code here. Its just too much code to put here.

Comment: Well, this skeleton code (once you add in the missing details) will execute in 1 request. Is there anything about it you don't understand?

Comment: Thanks again Jak. I am able to understand your code. Just need to put the whole thing (mvc) together to make sure it works. Will leave feedback soon.